# What danger signs indicate health issues when aquiring a new dog?

Tags: dogs, health, adoption

I am considering buying or adopting a new dog, and was wondering what signs I should look for to indicate health issues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Health issues" is such a broad brush... So, a general answer would be to examine the dog and make sure everything seems correct and use some common sense.

Are they clean, well kept, groomed, skinny/fat, breathing normally?

You can also get them out on a leash and make sure they walk/run correctly (no limping or favoring). Maybe let them out in a fenced area... watch for any signs of abnormal behavior.

Check the eyes, are they clouded or abnormal?

Generally spend some time with the dog and use your common sense.

If you are looking for a more specific health issue, list that in the question.

Answer (score 4):

HEALTH ISSUES SIGNS

Each disease comes with its own symptoms but some common symptoms are

- The dog might be very thin and skinny.
- The dog might have lost a lot of hair.
- The dog might also scoot a lot.
- The dog might have a dry and rough coat.

For more dog diseases and signs, see : [Common Dog Diseases: Signs, Symptoms and Treatments](http://www.hillspet.com/dog-care/dog-diseases.html)